# Can people automate Windows apps installation?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-installer, ansible, chef

I understand a Linux application installation can be automated through a script, but I am not so sure if this is true in Windows world. Here I have specific scenario.

I want to install Word onto a Windows 10 machine. Normally, I would select and click through the buttons along the installation wizard (and I guess that is 99% of user's way of installation).

Now, I am wondering if I could achieve the above manual process in a fully automated way. If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It ... depends.

Most programs use [Windows Installer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer), which is a Windows API with a [standard package format](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978328.aspx) (MSI) and flags for [scripted install/uninstall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367988.aspx). These can also be deployed [via Group Policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372058(v=vs.85).aspx) in corporate networks.

Some programs will have a custom installer, though most of those have their own scripted install methods. For example, [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setupcmdline.htm), [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html#installerusage) or [InstallShield](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm).

Microsoft Office uses something different yet again: as of 2013, the default installation method is [Click-To-Run](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219427.aspx). I'm not sure if this allows scripted installs in the [standard home/business versions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Download-and-install-or-reinstall-Office-365-or-Office-2016-on-a-PC-or-Mac-4414eaaf-0478-48be-9c42-23adc4716658), but you can check if any flags are available by running `setup.exe /?`. There *are* [deployment tools](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-the-Office-2016-Deployment-Tool-bb5b62d9-1168-47e9-9d54-15a958acfcca) for larger businesses. There is also a Volume License version, which comes as a traditional ISO with MSI installer.

Answer (score 0):

Program installation isnt some cryptic process. The core of any install is typical creating a folder and copying files.  Past that, there might be some registry modification. Unless we are discussing something uniquely complex, that's all there is to it.

You could automate the install of Word fairly easily. You can use any installer making program that can take a snapshot of the computer before the installation and after. Then it compares the difference between then and creates an installer. This method works, but there can be some drawbacks, depending on the situation.